# Slow response of post method of https request using httpc erlang module

Tags: ssl, erlang, httpclient, erlang-otp, handshake

Our Application (which uses existing Erlang OTP R15B01 modules) sends https request to external authentication server and it gets reply and seems work fine under normal cases. But under heavy loads some requests are failing since they are consuming more time to do SSL handshake.

I have observed the following things during SSL handshake:

- client is taking (our application) nearly 80 sec to send the certificate after server hello is done with server certificate
- since our server expects to complete the request-response in 30 sec otherwise it drops the connection hence results in connection failures and affects the performance of application severely

Finally, I would like to know:

- Is  our application failing  to invoke the client certificate quickly? I mean does `httpc` module do the file/IO related operations to invoke the certificates which results to slow response under heavy loads?
- Does Erlang have any limitations in SSL handshake procedure?

Comment: @MattDMo Did you ever receive any resolution or explanation to this issue? We are currently experiencing the exact same symptoms.